# In Maleficent, where is King Henry’s wife and Princess Leila’s mother?

Tags: maleficent

In the beginning of Maleficent, King Henry led an attack against the Moors, but Maleficent injured him. On his deathbed, he promised the throne to whoever would kill Maleficent, which led to Stefan cutting her wings off and presenting them to the King, thus he becomes Princess Leila’s husband and the new King.

But where was the Queen (King Henry’s wife) during this?

Did King Henry kill her to have all the power? Was she a fairy queen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know. King Henry and his daughter Leila are minor characters and their backstories aren't well developed. It's not known how he gained the throne or who his parents were, nor who his wife was or her fate. Certainly he places a lot of stock in 'royal blood', so at the very least we know that he's an aristocrat and his wife likely was one as well, and given his hatred for all things magical, it's very unlikely that she wasn't human.

> Stefan beamed. He’d finally done it. He’d overcome his status as a
> poor orphan to become something great. “I shall do my best to be a
> worthy successor, Your Majesty.”
>
> “Successor? You?” Henry gaped at him in surprise.
>
> “As by your edict.”
>
> The king allowed himself a throaty laugh. **“You? Your blood is not
> worthy.** You are a servant, nothing more. I don’t even know your name!”
>
> <sub><sup>[Maleficent - Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21949771-maleficent)</sup></sub>

His daughter (the Princess Leila) is in her 30's, so her mother would be likely to be in her mid-to-late 40s or early 50's by the time the film takes place, which was relatively close to the [normal life-expectancy for an aristocratic woman in medieval times](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-economic-history/article/lifespans-of-the-european-elite-8001800/BE252C4B25C4AAC29ED62D591A1675AC).

**In short, given her total absence from the film, she's probably dead.**

Comment: I like to think that King Henry’s Queen was called Talia.

Comment: Incidentally, in the real world, the monarch is usually only *one* of the king or the queen, not both of them (and traditionally, if it's the queen, then her husband is called a "prince" instead of a "king"). If the king decides to pass his crown on to some random commoner, in the days before they had parliaments, or parliament-like-things, he could probably just do that, without asking her majesty's permission (because she's just "his wife" as far as the law is concerned).

Comment: Beware the trap of infant mortality. Those life expectancy estimates must be interpreted with care, because they include children and infants who died early, which skews the statistics. Once someone survived childhood, their average lifespan was likely higher than you are suggesting.

Comment: Also, childbirth has to be taken into account too. The life expectancy of a woman who survived bearing children (say, someone who made it to 40 or 50 years old) would have been notably higher, once that major cause of death was out of the way.